# Best way to do absolute import in python from different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to do absolute import in my python project. I referred to [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)  but all the approaches had some drawback.

Following is my directory structure. All my source code are present in `Bank/src/`

[image: structure]

File contents are

**module1a.py**

```
DEMO = '123'
```

**module2a.py**

```
from module1.module1a import DEMO
print (DEMO)
```

**a.py**

```
from module1 import module1a
print (module1a.DEMO)
```

I want to execute my code from bank directory

***When I execute a.py it works***

```
(base) ➜  Bank python src/a.py
123
```

***When I execute module2a.py it fails***

```
(base) ➜  Bank python src/module2/module2a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/module2/module2a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module1.module1a import DEMO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'
```

Yes, my src is not in PYTHONPATH that's why it is failing.

I tried the following ways and all works

***Approach 1:***

```
(base) ➜  Bank PYTHONPATH=src python src/module2/module2a.py
123
```

Is it a good practice?

***Approach 2:***

Using something like this.

```
import os
import sys
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.append(parentdir)
```

Issue: I need to add it in all python files which I execute (in case of multiple entry points in the project)

***Approach 3:***

By creating setup using setuptools

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='myproject', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

Issue: since my code is in src directory, I am not able to change package name, and I have to import like `from src.module1.module1a import DEMO` I want something like `from myproject.module1.module1a import DEMO`

Comment: Your third item doesn't seem to be complete. If you create an installable module and install it (perhaps with `pip install -e .`in your virtual environment) you should be able to use the module as if it was installed system-wide.

Comment: Also `PYTHONPATH=src python -m myproject`

Comment: if you're running `module2a.py` from your module2a directory, then you could simply add `sys.path.append(..)` to the top of your module before importing your other modules.

Comment: @tripleee Yes did in my environemnt using pip install -e . as suggested by @np8 in that link that I shared on the top. But I want to import it as `myproject` and not `src`

Comment: Maybe add `package_dir={'': 'src'},` to the `setup()` parameters.